# Embedded Elasticsearch Server - Installing Plugins

Tags: spring, maven, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch 2.4.3 in my Spring Boot Application with following properties

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-name=Testenvironment
spring.data.elasticsearch.repositories.enabled=false
spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.http.enabled=true
spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.node.name=developertesting
spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.path.data=target/elasticsearch-data/
```

I have to use a phonetic filter but for this I have to install the plugin with my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-analysis-phonetic</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

But when I create my indices with the following plugin

```
        "my_metaphone":{
            "type": "phonetic",
            "encoder": "beidermorse",
            "languageset":"german",
            "rule_type":"exact",
            "replace": false
        }
```

the server response with the error, that type "phonetic" is unknown.....

**EDIT**

Elasticsearch is running as **embedded cluster**

Answer (score 4):

A colleague and i found a way to activate plugins in a Spring boot
application with an embedded elasticsearch.

Please verify, if this solution works for you as well.

We added a new ElasticsearchConfig class into our project.
In the ElasticsearchConfig we explicit create a Node with our
settings, we like to set.
We extended the Node class to add the plugins we would like to use.

After this changes it worked fine for us, the whole config class looks
like this:

```
    import org.elasticsearch.Version;
    import org.elasticsearch.client.Client;
    import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings;
    import org.elasticsearch.node.Node;
    import org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalSettingsPreparer;
    import org.elasticsearch.plugin.analysis.AnalysisPhoneticPlugin;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.config.EnableElasticsearchRepositories;

    import java.util.Collections;

    @Configuration
    @EnableElasticsearchRepositories
    public class ElasticsearchConfig {


        @Value("${spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-name:elasticsearch}")
        private String clusterName;

        @Value("${spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.path.home:/tmp/data}")
        private String pathHome;

        @Value("${spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.path.log:/tmp/log}")
        private String pathLog;

        @Bean
        public Client elasticsearchClient() {
            Settings.Builder settings = Settings.settingsBuilder();
            settings.put("node.local", true);
            settings.put("cluster.name", clusterName);
            settings.put("http.enabled", false);
            settings.put("path.home", pathHome);
            settings.put("path.log", pathLog);
            Node node = new LocalNode(settings.build()).start();
            return node.client();
        }

        private static class LocalNode extends Node {
            LocalNode(Settings settings) {

super(InternalSettingsPreparer.prepareEnvironment(settings, null),
                        Version.CURRENT,
                        Collections.singleton(AnalysisPhoneticPlugin.class));
            }
        }
    }
```

The default node will be created with null value for the plugins collection. That's why it's not possible to add and load plugins. In this case we extend the node class and overwrite the constructor to load the plugins which are needed for our setup.

Hopefully it helps you to find your solution. Feel free to change the
setup to your needs and post your solution if you found it.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to install the [`phonetic` plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/5.1/analysis-phonetic.html) on your ES server as it doesn't come bundled with it:

```
bin/plugin install analysis-phonetic
```

Comment: And where I have to insert this command? My Elasticsearchcluster starts when my Spring Boot app is started.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I didn't get that you were running an embedded ES server.

Comment: No problem, added it to the Question!

Comment: Can you show the code where you create your elasticsearch client?

Comment: I don't create the client on my own. Spring data elasticsearch does start the client/cluster with my properties (shown in the question). My hope that there is a property-name like "properties.plugins=analysis-phonetic" or something like that